# Problema con estilos css cuando paso variables por GET en PHP

Tags: php, html, css

Estoy enviando una variable por medio del metodo GET en PHP, lo recibe y ejecuta las acciones correctamente, el problema es con los estilos CSS, el procedimiento es el siguientes:

1- envio $id por medio del metodo GET desde AppTarea/index.php

```
<div class="opciones">

    <a href="Modelo/editar.php/?id=<?php echo $datos['id']; ?>">
        <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o editar"></i>
    </a>

</div>
```

2- Modelo/editar.php recibe la varible, antes de recibir la variable $id la pagina se ve asi --> editar.php, y recibe los estilos de CSS

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero luego ya no los recibe por que la url cambia al recibir la variable --> editar.php?id=1

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se que esta pasando, alguien puede ayudar.

Codigo completo de AppTarea/index.php, los datos vienen de la base de datos.

```
<?php 
include_once('Modelo/Tareas.php');
 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>App Terea</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="App">
        <h1 class="nombre">TARE-APP</h1>
        <h2>Tareas Creadas</h2>
        <?php 
            $tarea = new Tareas();
            $resul = $tarea -> selectTarea();
            foreach ($resul as $datos) { ?> 

                <div class="tarea" id="1">
                    <div class="fecha_hora">
                        <h3><?php echo $datos['hora']; ?> </h3>
                        <h3><?php echo $datos['fecha']; ?></h3>
                    </div>
                    <section class="info">
                        <h1><?php echo $datos['titulo']; ?></h1>
                        <p><?php echo $datos['descripcion']; ?></p>
                    </section>
                    <div class="opciones">
                        <a href="Modelo/editar.php/?id=<?php echo $datos['id']; ?>""><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o editar" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                        <a href="Modelo/eliminar.php/?id_tarea=<?php echo $datos['id']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-trash eliminar" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>

        <a href="Crear-Tarea"><div class="btnCrearTarea"> <span class="fa fa-plus"></span></div></a>
    </div>          
</body>
</html>
```

Codigo completo de Modelo/editar.php

```
<?php 
include_once('../Modelo/Tareas.php');
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
$tarea_vieja = New Tareas();
$result = $tarea_vieja -> selectTarea($id);

 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="Es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Crear Nueva Tarea</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/estilos.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="App">
    <h1 class="nombre">TARE-APP</h1>
    <a href="../index.php"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left flecha_volver" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    <h2>Crear nueva tarea</h2>
    <?php foreach ($result as $datos) { ?> 
        <form action="" method="post">
            <input type="text" value="<?php echo $datos['titulo']; ?>" name="titulo" required placeholder="Titulo Tarea" class="titulo" ><br>
            <textarea name="descripcion" maxlength="100" cols="22" rows="5" autocomplete="on" placeholder="Descripcion" class="descripcion"> <?php echo $datos['descripcion']; ?> </textarea><br>
            <input type="text" value="100" class="caracteres"><br>
            <input type="time" value="<?php echo $datos['hora']; ?>" name="hora" required class="hora"><br>
            <input type="date" value="<?php echo $datos['fecha']; ?>" name="fecha" required class="fecha"><br>

            <input type="submit" value="Editar" name="editar" class="btn_crear">
        </form>
    <?php } ?>
</div>

<?php 

if(isset($_POST['editar']) and !empty($_POST['editar'])) {
    $titulo_nuevo = $_POST['titulo'];
    $desc_nuevo   = $_POST['descripcion'];
    $hora_nuevo   = $_POST['hora'];
    $fecha_nuevo  = $_POST['fecha'];

    // Pasar datos al objeto de la clase Tareas para actualizar
    $tarea = new Tareas($titulo_nuevo, $desc_nuevo, $hora_nuevo, $fecha_nuevo);
    $tarea -> updateTarea($id);
    echo "<div id='msm'> <p> Tarea actualizada </p> </div>";
}


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: de donde sacas la variable $datos? pega tu código completo

Comment: Puede que algo extraño ocurra cuando haces esta llamada: `$tarea -> updateTarea($id);`, desde un error hasta una nueva recarga de la página ignorando los estilos css. De todos modos recargar la página, aparte de lo **feo** e **incómodo** que es, supone un **consumo de recursos inncesarios**, cuando puedes hacer la petición a la base de datos por Ajax, traer los nuevos datos de forma totalmente transparente para el usuario y **actualizar el contenido sin moverte de la página**. Sugiero que explores esa posibilidad, que es lo que se suele hacer en estos casos. Aquí en SO hay varios ejemplos.

Answer (score 1):

creo que el problema esta en estas lineas de codigo

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
```

el navegador esta buscando los estilos en

```
www.loquesea.com/editar.php?id=1css/estilos.css
```

intenta cambiar eso por unas lineas fijas 
ej:

```
href="www.loquesea.com/css/estilos.css">
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que sucede es que la nueva página con el id en el url, no apunta a donde está el CSS. Lo que puedes hacer es modularizar tu proyecto, creando un nuevo archivo .php para el `header` (puede ser `header.php`), incluirás todas las llamadas a archivos externos e internos que necesites cargar en tu body, desde estilos, scripts, etc.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>App Terea</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
</head>
```

Luego sólo deberás hacerle un `require_once` dentro de cualquier página `.php` que crees, con la ruta de tu header justo como haces con `tareas.php`. Seguido, deberás abrir con las etiquetas del `<body>` y comenzar a trabajar normalmente.

```html
<?php 
  require_once('header.php');
  include_once('../Modelo/Tareas.php');
?>

<body>

<!-- Todo tu contenido -->

</body>
```

Lo bueno de hacer esto, es que si necesitas modificar algo en el `header` sólo deberás hacerlo 1 vez en un único archivo y se aplicará para el resto donde lo incluyas. Esto también es aplicable para el `footer`.